# End http-server task after localhost:8080 is closed

Tags: windows, batch-file, exe, httpserver

I have an issue with something I've working on, I want an angular build to run locally from a desktop shortcut, the way I'm doing this is with a .bat file with this code

```
@ECHO OFF
:: Some text
ECHO ...Starting application on your default browser...
TITLE MyAPP
::Launch the server
http-server -p 8081 -o http://localhost:8081/index.html -s
::Closing the server
::EXIT
PAUSE
```

So, if a create a setup with the main folder and this batch file, I can create a desktop shortcut with no problem, and it works perfectly. The thing now is the CMD windows shows all the time until I close it, I tried using the Batch to Exe Program to run it invisible, but the problem is the process is always on (because I cannot close it from the cmd window) what I want to know, how can I end the http-server task from the bat file once the browser tab is closed?

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `http-server` is an executable, and you intend to be able to close it from the same batch file, you may need to `start` it! e.g. `start http-server -p ...`. If you're running the batch file from a shortcut, then you should at least be able to set that shortcut to run minimised. I know it's not the same as invisible, because you'd see it flash up first, but that may be acceptable. Also when using `start`, there are options with that command which may help; enter `start /?` at the Command Prompt for its usage information.

Comment: Yes, I think start the CMD minimised is the right way to do it, but is all because I'm doing it like this (I know Electron, I know I could do it that way, but I don't really know much about it), so I'll do it this way for now, it's an easy solution, thanks.